# Javascript mark substrings onchange event

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search, replace

I am trying to highlight substrings of a large string. The following code only highlights if the substring is the first letter of the large string. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

```
 function search() {
        var text = document.getElementById("searchText").value;

        if (!text) return;

        var regex =  new RegExp(text, 'gi');
        var str = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
        var n=str.match(regex);

            document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML.replace(str, '<span style="background-color:clear;">'+str+'</span>'); // clear 
            document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML.replace(n, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">'+n+'</span>');


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nfpeA/)

```
function search() {
    var hid = document.getElementById('hidtxt').value;
    if(hid.length == 0) hid.value=document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
        var text = document.getElementById("searchText").value;
       if (!text) return;
        var regex =  new RegExp(text, 'gi');
            document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = hid.replace(regex, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">$&</span>');


    }
```

Comment: You could use `$&` instead of concatenating `text`.

Comment: Thanks @plalx i dint think about it while fixing OP issue.. :)

Answer (score 0):

str.match(regex) returns an array which is why the replace does not work properly.

the replace method can accept a regexp which is what you should supply to it (to implement global search).

```
document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = str.replace(regex, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">'+text+'</span>');
```